# Finding the rotation matrix between two vectors in Python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am trying to write a code that gives me the rotation matrix between two vectors. I have tried the code given as an answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142959/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-two-vectors-in-3d-space). I first make it calculate the rotation matrix and then test it to see if it gives the correct answer. However, it doesn't seem to be giving the correct answer. Could anyone help with why I can't get the correct answer with this?

The Code is below:

```
import numpy as np 

def rotation_matrix_from_vectors(vec1, vec2):

    a, b = (vec1 / np.linalg.norm(vec1)).reshape(3), (vec2 / np.linalg.norm(vec2)).reshape(3)
    v = np.cross(a, b)
    c = np.dot(a, b)
    s = np.linalg.norm(v)
    kmat = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0], 0]])
    rotation_matrix = np.eye(3) + kmat + kmat.dot(kmat) * ((1 - c) / (s ** 2))
    return rotation_matrix

#from here it is the code I have written to test this function
vector1 = array([0,1,0])
vector2 = array([-1,0,1])

rot = rotation_matrix_from_vectors(vector1,vector2)
rotated = np.dot(rot,vector1)

print(rotated)
```

This prints vector [-0.707, 0, 0.707] instead of [-1, 0, 1].

Comment: The norm of `[-0.707, 0, 0.707]` is 1. Does that help you?

Comment: Yes, I can't see anything wrong. the input vector has norm 1, the rotation matrix has determinant 1, the rotated vector has norm 1. Hard to see a problem here.

Comment: Note that the rotation matrix is not designed to map vector1 onto vector2 exactly, but to map vector1 onto a vector parallel to vector2.  Which it is doing.

Comment: Ah thanks! that helps a lot. I think that was the thing I misunderstood

Comment: @ToykanOzdeger Note that the first thing that is done with vec2 in the calculation is to normalise it.

Comment: Thanks! that helps

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?