# rotate a mesh in python to be parallel to a vector

Tags: python, open3d, trimesh

I have two meshes (call them A and B) which I am interacting within python using the open3d library (happy to use `import trimesh` or something else if it works better). Mesh A is a curved structure and mesh B approximates to a flatter surface.

I need to rotate the meshes so that the surface I am interested in is facing the camera.
To identify the surfaces that I need I have written functions to turn the meshes into point clouds and create the best fit sphere for mesh A and a best-fit plane for mesh B. These work really well and match the objects nicely.

I need to rotate the meshes and have gotten stuck with how to perform the rotation.

The input data that I have:

for mesh A:
centroid of mesh A coords and coords of its best fit sphere (+ its radius) - I want to rotate the mesh so that is perpendicular to the vector described by the above data?

for mesh B:
centroid of mesh B coords and vector of the normal of the best fit plane - I want to rotate the mesh so that is perpendicular to the vector described by the above data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!
created two vectors as numpy arrays, vector 1 and vector2 and found the open3d commands to center the mesh and apply the rotation matrix between the two vectors. Think this is susceptible to gimbal lock but I cant get my head around quaternions and it works well enough for my usage scenario.

```
#this function to create a rotation matrix was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/q/63525482/6010071
def rotation_matrix_from_vectors(vec1, vec2):

    a, b = (vec1 / np.linalg.norm(vec1)).reshape(3), (vec2 / np.linalg.norm(vec2)).reshape(3)
    v = np.cross(a, b)
    c = np.dot(a, b)
    s = np.linalg.norm(v)
    kmat = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0], 0]])
    rotation_matrix = np.eye(3) + kmat + kmat.dot(kmat) * ((1 - c) / (s ** 2))
    return rotation_matrix
#to move the mesh to 0,0,0 (using open3d library)
mesh.translate(-mesh.get_center())
# to rotate the mesh to variable vector2, i set it to np.array([0,0,1]) = in line with z axis again using open3d library
mesh.rotate(rotation_matrix_from_vectors(vector1,vector2),center=(0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that library, but maybe you could try to rotate your objects throughout Affine2D() class, of Matplotlib.

Specifically, try with this function:
`mtransforms.Affine2D().rotate()`

First, you will have to import it: `matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms`

Answer (score 0):

As this is still the top ranking google hit for "python rotate mesh", and even though OP found his solution, I'd like to explain how I did it (in case people don't want to use the open3D lib).

Since I am too lazy to write a transformation matrices myself, I used the scipy lib to build them from e.g. euler angles (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html)

From then on, to transform each point in the mesh according to the generated rotation matrix, I did:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
```

...

```
r = R.from_euler('zyx', [0, angle1, angle2], degrees=True)
Rot = r.as_matrix() # Rotation matrix

# Apply the rotation matrix, but do this from mesh form (piecewise for each element though numpy)
rotmesh_X = mesh_X * Rot[0, 0] + mesh_Y * Rot[0, 1] + mesh_Z * Rot[0, 2]
rotmesh_Y = mesh_X * Rot[1, 0] + mesh_Y * Rot[1, 1] + mesh_Z * Rot[1, 2]
rotmesh_Z = mesh_X * Rot[2, 0] + mesh_Y * Rot[2, 1] + mesh_Z * Rot[2, 2]
```

Perhaps there is a function in numpy that avoids the expansion into the elements of the rotational matrix, but aside from the code verbosity, this is  works fast already as all elements of the mesh are computed in only a few steps (vs iterating over every element)

Hope this helps someone